# How to print each element from the collection array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing one controller inside that controller i write one collection from that collection i want to print each element inside the array for that i am writing some function with foreach method ,i am unable to iterate each element from the collection array please help me to acheive this thing..

`UserController.php`

```
 public function calculator(){
     $collection=collect(['5','2','1','50'])->map(function($name){
      //   return ($name+20);
      foreach($name as $n){
        return $n;
      }
     });
     return $collection;
   }
```

`Expected output`
`5 2 1 50`

`Error i am getting`

```
ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file /home/payarc/Desktop/newLaravel/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but the map function is just for changing the values of the collection. `$name` is '5', '2', .. so you try to do `foreach ("5" as $n)`

Answer (score -1):

Map function is not required for iterating, you simply use foreach method alone

```
public function calculator(){
     $collection=collect(['5','2','1','50']);
      foreach($collection as $n){
        echo $n;
      } 
   }
```

I hope this will meet your requirement